# Detecting unicode strikethrough characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, strikethrough

I use a modified version of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/billmei/8856977) to have **unicode strikethrough characters** of a string. It is in a utility file like:

```
const StrikethroughStr = (str) => {
  return [...str].reduce((acc, char) => {
    return acc + char + '\u0336'
  }, '')
}
```

And this way, I can have a string some chars are strikethrough and some others are normal.

So, how can I determine that **a char at a specific index is strikethrough or not**?

Applying a regex is the first solution I can think of, but I am not sure how the logic of one would be built in this case; or if there are non-regex ways.

**Example Usage:**

```
console.log(someRegex.test('S̶'))
// expected output: false


console.log(someRegex.test('S'))
// expected output: true
```

Comment: Adding combining characters like U+0336 means you're dealing with *extended grapheme clusters*, not individual codepoints representing characters . Accessing strings by index does not play well with Unicode text because of these. What you need is something that iterates through each cluster at a time, and look for that codepoint in the Nth cluster. (I don't know the specifics of how to do that in javascript)

Comment: Pearlish point for that *extended grapheme clusters*, didn't know about them. Yet, my emphasis was not on heavily on indices -pardon me if the question looks so. But I mainly try to find out, let's say, **S̵** *is* a strikethrough char, unlike **S**.